# Calling several SQL procedures at once with Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x, mysql-python

I have made a stored procedure in MySQL which accepts several arguments and does its things.
And while I have no problem to execute the following query in MySQL

```
CALL my_pr(var1, var2, var3); CALL my_pr(var4, var5, var6);
```

When I try to execute it (or any other 2 statements at once) via Python I get the following error:

> Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

But when I am trying to execute them one by one - everything works smoothly.

I am adding each statement to a list and then execute it via:

```
    for stm in sql_stms:
        mycursor.execute(stm)
        mydb.commit()
```

Where I set each stm to be a single query or a multiple statement query in some code above. And my sql_stms contain several INSERT, SELECT and DELETE queries and tens (or sometimes hundreds) of queries for a stored procedure.

My goal is to speed up the running process and currently the slowest part in my code is submitting queries to SQL, so I believe that when I submit multiple queries at once it will work slightly faster.

Any ideas and suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: you could build a sql file, save it and run it in the shell, speeding up several commnads is imposible.

Comment: One SQL process can handle one SQL command at a time. The error "Commands out of sync" means that you have not processed the first procedure before submitting the second one. Running multiple commands parallel might improve the speed (depending on the actions), but would require multiple connections. You should take a look at what the procedures are doing and optimize those.

Comment: I like very much these suggestions. I may try to build and .sql file today and try its speed.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not expecting more than one resultSet, try setting the multi result to true before executing

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor(multi=True)
```

Comment: multi=true can be an argument only for the execution class "mycursor.execute(sql, multi=True)". However, this is not a solution to this issue, but thank you for the idea anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

The interface is not designed to easily get two "result sets" at once.

There is very little advantage in trying to run two statements together.  Simply run them one at a time.

You can, on the other hand, build a third SP that makes those two `CALLs`.  But, again, why bother.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand terminology 100% correct, but I don't think I receive a result set in most of my queries as they are INSERTs and UPDATEs. So is there a workaround in this case?

Comment: Why do you need a workaround?  Why won't issuing the two statements separately be OK?

Comment: Actually I've made an sql file with bunch of queries and found that the speed os performing them is only slightly faster compared to sending them one by one from python code, so I think i would leave it this way :)